# Magento 2.1: How to get attribute value as text in response of product rest api

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, rest-api

I have created a custom attribute "color" and it has the values Red, Green, Blue. When I call `/V1/products/:sku` it shows the product details and also shows the `custom_attributes{"attribute_code":"color","value":"74"}`. I want the value of the attribute is "Red" instead of 74 (It's ID).

Comment: Please Help me.